# Insert Message in many folders using Graph API (Microsoft Outlook)

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, nestjs

In google mail API, a mail can have a list of parent Labels. So it can have multiple parents. I want to do similar in Outlook, but here we have to specifically define the ParentFolderId. Is it possible to do it in Outlook using graph API.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not designed to answer your questions if you haven't put any effort in finding answer yourself. Show us what have you tried so far and what didn't work.

Comment: Sure, @MarioNikolaus I will edit my question after putting more effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Exchange world, a message can only have a single parent. If you want a message to be present in multiple folders, it must be created in each and every folder. But these messages will be totally independent from each other, and can be modified or deleted without affecting any other messages.

There are search folders (you can see them in Outlook) that contains only pointers to messages in other folders (this is similar to what Google does), but most Outlook folders are not search folders.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation is pretty much clear, I will look into the search folders in outlook.